# populate range with values from one column based on values in another

Tags: excel, vba

Happy hump day all,
I'm hoping to get some help with this macro that I'm fairly certain has an easy solution but I'm missing a key factor.

**scenario:** I've got a named range that populates the combobox of a userform, I want to allow a user to add or remove choices from this range so the userform only contains choices for what they are working on *(in a user friendly fashion for the non excel savvy)*. There is a "master list" that contains dozens of choices to choose from, to the left of the list I've added a worksheet event on double click which adds a green check mark, indicating the item is selected.

**goal:** after making selections from the master list, I want the user to click a button which will run a macro to identify where there is a check mark to the left of the list and add the corresponding value to the named range on the next available row.

**issue:** my attempt at looping through each "P" (webdings 2 checkmark) and adding the value to the right is technically working but it is adding the values to the same cell resulting in only the last item checked off to remain.

how can I loop through each "P" and add it to a row separately?

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim lastrow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("named content")
lastrow = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("MasterList").Offset(, -1).Cells
    If c = "P" Then
    ws.Range("F" & lastrow).Value = c.Offset(, 1)
      End If
Next c
End Sub
```

I've played around with a few alterations and all end up with the same or similar result. Any help would be immensely appreciated! in the mean time I think I will attempt to add and remove each value when the check marks are added and see if that works better.

**EDIT:**   All; UGP answered my question perfectly but thought I would share the workaround I was going to use.

Whereas the original code identifies each checked value and adds them to the column upon running the macro, this worksheet event adds the value to the named range column upon double clicking to add the check mark next to the value in the master list, and likewise; removes the value from the named range column when the check mark is removed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim lastrow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("named content")
lastrow = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("MasterList").Offset(, -1)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If ActiveCell.Value = "P" Then
            ActiveCell.ClearContents
            For c = lastrow To 3 Step -1
            If ws.Cells(c, 6).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1) Then
            Cells(c, 6).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
            Next

        Else
            ActiveCell.Value = "P"
            ws.Range("F" & lastrow).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)
        End If
        Cancel = True
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So lets say the data of the named range starts in column B, so your green checkmark ( a shape?) would be in column A?

Comment: correct, the check mark symbols which are "P" are in the column to the left of the master list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pasting everything in the same row, because you didnt calculate the lastrow with every new value.

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim lastrow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("named content")
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("MasterList").Offset(, -1).Cells
    If c = "P" Then
        lastrow = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws.Range("F" & lastrow).Value = c.Offset(, 1)
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you UGP, I knew it must've been a simple flip of a line but I couldn't see it. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact fix, but might get you started in the right direction.  I'm assuming that your green check mark is a shape.  I don't know what type of shape it is, so you will have to change the line for that.  I used "Right Arrow" shapes to substitute.  It should put all the "checked" row numbers into an array that you can then use to get the data from those rows.

```
Public Sub LoopThroughShapes()
Dim Shape As Shape, myArray() As Variant, arrayCounter As Long

ReDim myArray(1 To 1)
arrayCounter = 1
For Each Shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If InStr(1, Shape.Name, "Right Arrow") <> 0 Then
        Shape.Select
        Debug.Print Shape.Name, Shape.TopLeftCell.Row
        ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To arrayCounter)
        myArray(arrayCounter) = Shape.TopLeftCell.Row
        arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It's a webdings 2 check mark which is a capital P. I wanted to take the value in the column to the right of each "P" and populate a third column with each of those values. Which I had for the most part but it was dropping the values in the same cell. many thanks for the idea though.